# Pushes on github that aren't mine

Tags: git, github

I've forked a repository on github, and regularly make pull requests to the parent. However I've found that sometimes the owner of the parent repository will make commits to the branches in **my** repository, before pulling in the result. This can be very troublesome, and I'm not sure how or why it's even possible - surely only **I** should have permission to make commits to **my** fork of the repository? I've added no collaborators, my fork it isn't part of a organization (although the parent is), and although my fork is public, I would still expect that to require pull requests.

Is there any way to tell who made the push, or how it was authorised?

Comment: "*parent repository*" It's called *upstream*. *Parent* is usually a repository with submodules… and even then the proper term is *superproject*.

Comment: Do you regularly pull from the upstream? That perhaps how new commits from the upstream enter your repository. Then you push them to your fork.

Comment: right, thanks for the syntactical corrections. And no, i'm not talking about commits I've pulled and then pushed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to unselect this checkbox in your pull requests:

[image]

GitHub normally allows maintainers to edit the branch the pull request refers to because if they find a little mistake, or something that they want to change to make your changes fit into the repository, they can do it by themselves.

Comment: Oh! That looks like it! Thanks @MarvinJWendt